# Nhibernate Linq In Clause

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Is it possible to get Nhibernate linq to generate a query with an "In" clause? e.g. - `Where AnID in (x,y,z)`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't know the state of nHibernate with respect to generating all the potential LINQ queries, but you should be able to use `.Contains()` to generate an IN.

```
var list = new int[] { x, y, x };
var q = db.Entities.Where( e => list.Contains( e.AnID ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

Agreed, this does work. I found the generated SQL for 'not in' to be strange though (as of 3.3.0 GA)

```
...
from
  mytable t0_
where
  case
    when t0_.testValue in (
              @p0 , @p1 , @p2
          ) then 1
          else 0
    end=@p3
@p0 = 9 [Type: Int32 (0)],
@p1 = 99 [Type: Int32 (0)],
@p2 = 109 [Type: Int32 (0)],
@p3 = False [Type: Boolean (0)],
...
```

Seems a bit odd to 'case' this when 'not in' would have been clearer (not that I plan on reading every line, but in a trace/profile maybe).

(... later that day ...)

I realized that the above 'strange' choice of SQL was only when I used

```
.Where(e => list.Contains(e.AnID) == false)
```

If I used

```
.Where(e => !list.Contains(e.AnID))
```

The SQL generated is much cleaner (using 'not in')

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate has an option IsIn part of RestrictionExtensions

> x => x.Name.IsIn( new[] {"a", "b"} )