# NHibernate Futures using Linq to query count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

I have this method below that queries over database to get for instance User, Orders or any entity for that matter. I want to know if the below query is optimal or do i have to tweak that.

Does the query do where, only after storing all records in the memory ?

Is there a way i can specify `Expression` for the filtering rather than `Func<>` ?

What it the optimal way to get Count, specifying a condition/where without much memory consumption?

**C# Sample Code**

```
public IList<TEntity> Find(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    //Criteria for creating
    ICriteria filterCriterea = _unitOfWork.CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(TEntity));

    //filtered result
    return filterCriterea.Future<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Comment: "Does the query do where, only after storing all records in the memory ?" : yes.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14647670/1236044 might be of some help.

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: @DanielSchilling V2.1.2  a strict requirement not to change the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are several things that you need to fix:

#### 1. Ask for an `Expression`, not a `Func`

Your `Find` method specifies that it wants a `Func`.  If you want an `Expression`, you have to say so:

```
public IList<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
```

#### 2. Use LINQ or `QueryOver` instead of `ICriteria`

Assuming you're not using an ancient version of NHibernate that doesn't have LINQ or QueryOver *(oddly, there are a LOT of people still using NHibernate 1.2.1 - I can't figure out why)*...

`ICriteria` doesn't understand `Expression`s.  Replace `CreateCriteria(typeof(TEntity))` with `Query<TEntity>()` or `QueryOver<TEntity>()` depending on which query syntax you prefer.

#### 3. `Where` should go before `Future`

You need to move the `Where` before the `Future`.  `Future` is used to batch several queries together so that they all get executed in one round trip to the database as soon as your code tries to evaluate the results of one of the "Future" queries.  At the point your above code calls `Future`, the query only consists of `CreateCriteria(typeof(TEntity))`, which just tells it which table to query against, like so:

```
select * from TEntity
```

If you want a where clause in there, you have to switch those method calls around:

```
filterCriterea.Where(predicate).Future<TEntity>()
```

This should give you a SQL query like:

```
select * from TEntity where ...
```

*It is very important to learn the difference between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`.*  You should notice that `Query` returns an `IQueryable`, whereas `Future` returns an `IEnumerable`.  Manipulating an `IQueryable` using `Expression`s will result in changes to the SQL that gets executed.  Manipulating an `IEnumerable` using a `Func` just changes the way you're looking at the in-memory data.

#### 4. `ToList` immediately after `Future` negates benefit of `Future`

`ToList` iterates over the collection that is passed to it and puts each element in a list.  The act of iterating over the collection will cause the Future query to be immediately executed, not giving you any chance to batch it together with other queries.  If you *must* have a list, you should just omit the `Future`.  I think however, that it would be a better idea to change your method to return an `IEnumerable`, which would give you the ability to batch this query together with other queries.  Like so...

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    var query = _unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Query<TEntity>();
    return query.Where(predicate).Future<TEntity>();
}
```

In order to take advantage of the query batching, you are probably going to have to rearrange the code that calls this `Find` method.  For example, instead of...

```
foreach (var openThing in thingRepository.Find(x => x.Status == Status.Open))
    CloseIt(openThing);

foreach (var negativeWhatsit in whatsitRepository.Find(x => x.Amount < 0))
    BePositive(negativeWhatsit);
```

... you should do this:

```
var openThings = thingRepository.Find(x => x.Status == Status.Open);
var negativeWhatsits = whatsitRepository.Find(x => x.Amount < 0);

// both queries will be executed here in one round-trip to database
foreach (var openThing in openThings)
    CloseIt(openThing);

foreach (var negativeWhatsit in negativeWhatsits)
    BePositive(negativeWhatsit);
```

Comment: AAhhh!!!  I completely overlooked the fact that you're trying to use expressions and LINQ-style filtering with ICriteria.  That's not possible.  If you want to use expressions, you need to use LINQ or QueryOver.  Editing...

Comment: `_unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Query<TEntity>();` why does Visual Studio complain me that the method Query does not exist, Is it because of NHibernate 2.1 ?

Comment: Yes.  LINQ support was officially added to NHibernate version 3.0, but you can add LINQ support to NHibernate 2.1 using the LINQ provider in nhcontrib: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Linq/1.0/.  After referencing NHibernate.Linq.dll, add `using NHibernate.Linq;` to the top of your file.  That will give you a `session.Linq<T>()` extension method (instead of `session.Query<T>()`).